# download files for only php users htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

**how could i do this with htaccess , please ?**

```
if (url has not parameter ?down=true) 
redirect back
else
do noting
end if
```

**example**

example.com/upload/file.pdf // it mustn't downlaod the file

example.com/upload/file.pdf?down=true // it must download the file

**please help me :)**

**that's my htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^upload/file/(.*) http\:\/\/www\.example\.org\/down.php?file=$1 [L]
```

**this is the down.php page**

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){ 
if(isset($_GET["file"])) $file = mysql_escape_string($_GET["file"]);
$file = "http://www.example.org/upload/file/".$file;
$file = preg_replace("/ /", "%20", $file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
//header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
readfile($file);
exit;

}else{
header('Location:login.php');
}
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable inside a `RewriteCond` for that checking for redirect like this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)down=true($|&)
RewriteRule example\.com\/upload\/file\.pdf /index.php [L]
```

if your `RewiteCond` has a `down=true` in the query string, then do not apply the following rule,else rewrites all request  to `/index.php`

Comment: thanks for your reply but could you write the full condition to my
because i failed